# Blocking object property

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, javafx

I wrote a small class that blocks in a method if the value is null. For some reason, it is throwing a `StackOverflowError`, what I am doing wrong?

```
public class BlockingObjectProperty<T> extends SimpleObjectProperty<T> {
    public T get() {
        if (super.get() == null) {
            addListener(((observableValue, t, t1) -> {
                synchronized (this) {
                    notifyAll();
                }
            }));
            synchronized (this) {
                try {
                    wait();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    throw new RuntimeException(e.getMessage(), e);
                }
            }
        }
        return super.get();
    }
}
```

Here is my test code:

```
BlockingObjectProperty<String> blockingObjectProperty = new BlockingObjectProperty<String>();
new Thread(){
    public void run(){
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        blockingObjectProperty.set("hello world");
    }
}.start();
System.out.println(blockingObjectProperty.get());
```

And here is a snippet of the exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at com.sun.javafx.binding.ExpressionHelper$SingleChange.<init>(ExpressionHelper.java:144)
    at com.sun.javafx.binding.ExpressionHelper.addListener(ExpressionHelper.java:69)
    at javafx.beans.property.ObjectPropertyBase.addListener(ObjectPropertyBase.java:87)
    at com.neonorb.commons.property.BlockingObjectProperty.get(BlockingObjectProperty.java:8)
    at javafx.beans.binding.ObjectExpression.getValue(ObjectExpression.java:50)
    at com.sun.javafx.binding.ExpressionHelper$SingleChange.<init>(ExpressionHelper.java:152)
    at com.sun.javafx.binding.ExpressionHelper$SingleChange.<init>(ExpressionHelper.java:144)
    at com.sun.javafx.binding.ExpressionHelper.addListener(ExpressionHelper.java:69)
    at javafx.beans.property.ObjectPropertyBase.addListener(ObjectPropertyBase.java:87)
    at com.neonorb.commons.property.BlockingObjectProperty.get(BlockingObjectProperty.java:8)
    at javafx.beans.binding.ObjectExpression.getValue(ObjectExpression.java:50)
    at com.sun.javafx.binding.ExpressionHelper$SingleChange.<init>(ExpressionHelper.java:152)
    at com.sun.javafx.binding.ExpressionHelper$SingleChange.<init>(ExpressionHelper.java:144)
    at com.sun.javafx.binding.ExpressionHelper.addListener(ExpressionHelper.java:69)
    at javafx.beans.property.ObjectPropertyBase.addListener(ObjectPropertyBase.java:87)
    at com.neonorb.commons.property.BlockingObjectProperty.get(BlockingObjectProperty.java:8)
```

Comment: @Alfie that's **super.**get() which calls the `get` method in the superclass.

Comment: You need to be aware that `notifyAll()` does not do _anything_ unless some other thread already is blocked in a `wait()` call.  How do you _guarantee_ that the one thread will already be waiting before the other thread calls `notify()`?

Comment: @jameslarge Because they will only be waiting if the value of the property is equal to null. If it is null, they need to wait for it to not be. Once the value is changed (not equal to null), the other threads can unblock. It is not necessary that threads **must** be blocking for it to work. As a side note, I switched to Locks instead of using wait/notify.

Comment: I don't see that:  Your get() method adds a listener, and then it waits().  I don't see any code that prevents the listener from being called before the get() method manages to `synchronize(this)`.

Comment: You said, "It is not necessary that threads must be blocking for it to work."  I don't understand:  _What_ is not necessary for _what_ to work?  If you are responding to my comment about what wait() and notify() do, then you should read the documentation.  If thread A calls `o.notify()` and then thread B calls `o.wait()`, then thread B will sleep forever or, until some other thread calls `o.notify()` a second time.

Comment: The notify *could* be called in the little time in between creating the listener, and waiting, I will have to consider that, but it is a very short amount of time. At the top of the `get()` method, there is a condition that checks if the value is null, then and only then does it wait for it to not be null. If the value is something else, it continues and returns the value. If null, it adds a listener to "wait" for a change, and then waits to be notified by the listener.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call `addListener` JavaFX asks the property for its current value (in ExpressionHelper.java:152), calling `getValue()` again. Then - since the value is still null - you add another listener and so on ad infinitum.

Comment: I renamed the method to `getBlocking()` and it works now.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to wait for some variable to become non-null:

```
private final Object myVarLock = new Object();
private MyType myVar;

MyType get_myVar() {
    synchronized(myVarLock) {
        while (myVar == NULL) {
            myVarLock.wait();
        }
        return myVar;
    }
}
```

And to set the variable:

```
void set_myVar(myType newValue) {
    synchronized(myVarLock) {
        myVar = newValue;
        myVarLock.notifyAll();
    }
}
```

**NOTES**

The getter waits in a loop.  This is necessary for strict correctness because the Java Langauge Spec allows `wait()` to return even when it has not been notified.  (a.k.a., *spurious wakeup*).

Even if spurious wakeups don't happen in your JVM or in your application, it still is smart to always use a loop.  The loop is essential in any algorithm where multiple consumer threads compete with one another to receive events.  The loop doesn't cost any more than an `if`, so you might as well just be in the habit of always using the loop.

The test of myVar and the assignment of myVar both are inside the `synchronized` blocks.  This is important.  If they weren't both synchronized then here is what could happen:

- Thread A enters the getter, tests `myVar` and finds that it equals NULL.
- Thread B enters the setter, sets `myVar` non-null, calls `myVarLock.notifyAll()`, returns.  The notification is *lost* because no other thread was waiting for it.
- Thread A calls `myVarLock.wait()` and waits forever, for an event that is never going to happen again.